# Windows 10 Freezes on WiFi connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, freeze, windows-10-v1607

I bought a PCI WiFi Card for my PC (GA-H81M-SP2V) and installed it. It shows up and can scan wifi for networks. The second I try to connect to my wifi (or any wifi) Windows hangs.

The WiFi Card is **TP-Link WN751ND**. It has the latest drivers from Windows.

How can I solve this? any help would be appreciated. I dont want to clean install Windows as this install has VS2015 installed and it took me few days to install that. Plus I have a few games' save data on it.

Regads

Comment: the card uses a AR9287 chipset. So try several drivers: http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=AR9287

Comment: i found a newer driver but it is a cab file. How would i use that? @magicandre1981

Comment: nvm... i should have used my brain before posting that comment... hehe

Comment: I tried installing the driver but it says the newest one is already installed. http://imgur.com/a/eHWaz this is my driver version and I installed **10.0.0.347** @magicandre1981

Comment: @magicandre1981 ok i installed one driver and the PC doesnt freeze instantly only after a few minutes of activity.

Answer (score 0):

The TP WIFI card uses a `AR9287` chipset. Open the [Microsoft Update catalog](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=AR9287) and try several driver versions, maybe one of them doesn't freeze the PC.

Comment: Updated the driver. But the Windows Still freezes after 10 mins of connection.

Comment: press CAPS LOCK during the free and look if the light on the keyboards toggles or not. If it toggles, you have a software freeze, if it doesn't toggle, you have a hardware based freeze.

Comment: it doesnt change. Nor caps lock neither num lock.

Comment: ok, so it is not related to any driver. if the PC is stable without the card, the card may have issues. Try a different WIFI card.

Comment: yes i have come to a similar conclusion that my card is busted. I installed Windows 7, 8, 10 and the card hung all of them. Somethimes even the reset button on the Case fails to work.